# Why does TortoiseHg randomly capitalize my file name on commit?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

The file is not capitalized in the directory.
There is nothing that would indicate that the file is different from any other file.
Yet, on commit, the file name is capitalized including the type "CS".
What's up with that?

Comment: What filesystem are you using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not just filenames. It can also happen to any segment of the file's path.

This was a recent bug in Mercurial itself on Windows ([discussion](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issue/1521/file-not-tracked-error)). It seems to be resolved in Mercurial 2.1, which will be included with TortoiseHg 2.3. There is a release candidate available, [TortoiseHg 2.3-rc](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg-winbuild/downloads), and the final release should be out in less than a week.

Comment: After upgrading TortoiseHg, how do we handle this issue?

Comment: There's no special 'handling', it just stops happening. I haven't had this issue since I upgraded to thg-2.3-hg-2.1, but a few apparently still see it. The last few comments in the discussion I linked to offer some workarounds, such as specifically adding files through shell extension, rather than letting the Workbench use `--addremove`.

Comment: I've seen that the issue stops for future files, but not for existing files. :(

Comment: Assuming, by "existing files", you mean files already tracked, then no it doesn't fix those. This is because he issue occurs at the time the files are added. Once the path is like that when it's added and you commit, that's that. You might be able to find some information on fixing them, but at the moment I can't think of anything other than using `hg convert` with a filemap or forgetting and re-adding them, neither of which are great solutions.